# Insert into database using textbox control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to insert data from control textbox into a database table; however say the user selects that they want to textboxes; then one ID in the textbox is entered in one row and the other ID is entered in another row in the database and I want it to entered as ID1 and ID2. I have 3 columns that user can enter in the IDs; so for instance they select 1 textbox then the data in that one textbox is entered and other columns remain null.

Update

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("PP_CreateIDNumber", connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usernum", lblSheet.Text);

                        int counter = 1;
                        foreach (TextBox textBox in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                        {
                                string seal = string.Format("@seal{0}", counter++);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(seal, textBox.Text);

                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                         }
```

}

```
foreach (TextBox textBox in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("PP_CreateIDNumber", connection))
    {                  
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userNum", lblUser.Text);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID1", textBox.Text);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID2", textBox.Text);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID3", textBox.Text);

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm.Parameters.Clear();
        }
    }    
}
```

Stored Procedure

```
@usernum varchar(20),
    @ID1 nchar(10),
    @ID2 nchar(10),
    @ID3 nchar(10),



AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into Student values(@usernum, @ID1,@ID2, @ID3)
```

[image]

Comment: What parameter names is your stored procedure expecting?

Comment: @stuartd userNum int,
 ID1 nchar(10),
 ID2 nchar(10),
 ID3 nchar(10), but it should expect it at all times

Comment: I'm not sure why the for...each. Wouldn't you just use the 3 textboxes you're finding in the for...each as your parameter values? That for each would add three rows each containing 3 columns with the same values as the current textbox found in the for...each iteration.

Comment: OK, well you're passing `lblUser.Text` which is a string to a parameter which expects an int. Don't use `AddWithValue`, use `Add` and pass a DBType and the correct value type. It looks like your problem is that you're overwriting all three values with each textbox, so your best bet is to get rid of the foreach and add each textbox value individually.

Comment: yeah I understand but how would I get this part because it is a textbox control

Comment: @CharlesMay; can you give me an example please

Comment: what are the names of the textboxes being found in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()? I'm making assumptions that there's only 3 by your explanation. Assuming there's 3 txt1, txt2 and txt3 you would just replace `textbox.Text` with txt1.Text  for ID1, txt2.Text for ID2, etc... and get rid of the for...each loop altogether.

Comment: but what the user selects 2 textbox instead of 3 textboxes then how do I capture it to allow the 3rd column to be null

Comment: @CharlesMay; as i was saying the textboxes might vary; one user may want to use six textboxes while another uses 3

Comment: Is it such that you plan to write ONE row PER textbox, where all other columns are NULL? E.g. for Textbox 1 you will fill ID1 column but not ID2 and ID3? Just use a for loop and let the index help decide which column to set null and which to set not null.

Comment: yes something like that; I was try using the for loop then I wasn't getting the values from the textbox. Can you give me an example please and i'll work with that]

Comment: How does your storedprocedure handle more than 3 textboxes? I'm missing something here apparently. This keeps screaming a 1 to many relationship between two tables but I can't grasp the concept of what you're trying to store here.

Comment: i wanted to stored all the data in one row rather than multiple rows. something like what @Trioj; but it seems like it can work; and I don't know how to handle

Comment: I would love to type you a legitimate and nuanced answer but I am mobile at the moment and I nevertheless want to point you to a way of solving for one row: instantiate your command outside of your loop. Add your static parameters like usernum. Next, loop over the text boxes, and using a counter to help provide the parameter name, add the parameter name and value. Then execute your proc (once, outside of the loop).

Comment: @Trioj, is it possible to give me an example I could work with to get a better understanding\

Comment: I've added an answer with an example of what I think you want. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Trioj; the counter not incrementing

Comment: Hmm. Wrapped up at the moment, but try using `command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@ID{counter}", textBox.Text);
counter += 1;`

Comment: @Trioj, sorry to be bothering you but for the stored procedure, you wouldn't list out the parameters

Comment: I believe that what you have is a table that looks something like this:
UserNum | ID1 | ID2 | ID3. The problem is that I don't know what those IDs are. This may be a valid design. However if all of those IDs represent the same kind of foreign key relationship (they all refer back to the same table), then it may be better to have a table with a design like this: UserNum | ID or UserNum | ID | Sequence. In which case you are creating many rows, one for each usernum/id pair, instead of one row with all ids. There are pros and cons to both approaches depending on your data and what you do with it

Comment: To be clear: the answer that I gave you was intended to work with what I *believe* your stored proc probably looks like already without any changes. The considerations that I think you should make are for your enrichment as an engineer. You can solve the issue without rework, or you can choose to rework.

Comment: With the table and proc you've shown, and the information provided so far, I believe the answer that I provided should work as-is.

Comment: @Trioj; can you assist me with another question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then I believe you want something like this:

```
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("PP_CreateIDNumber", connection)) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userNum", lblUser.Text);

        int counter = 1;
        foreach(TextBox textBox in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@ID{counter++}", textBox.Text);
        }

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

If you do not have access to a framework version supporting string interpolation in the manner I have used it above, you can use `string.Format("@ID{0}", counter++)` and that should be sufficient for any framework version.

You should additionally consider the order in which you should iterate over your textboxes and whether you have a need to impose a specific order. You should also consider validating that the number of textboxes does not exceed the number of foreign key columns to which you will be inserting data. Lastly, you should consider whether the design of this table is actually optimal. Since you are holding many foreign keys here, you should consider having a table designed for a one-to-many relationship.

Not having intimate knowledge of your schema makes it difficult to provide a specific suggestion here, but consider a table that has a UserNum column and simply an Id column (potentially even an additional column that indicates the sequence/order of the identities). Instead of using one row to hold the data, use many rows. I do not know your requirements and again your schema, so I feel sheepish about pushing you to a potentially unnecessary redesign of a table, but you should at least consider whether it is applicable here.

Lastly, consider not performing data access within your user interface. Have your user interface reference a separate assembly that holds classes that understand how to provide your UI with the data it requires.

All of that being said, I believe the code example gets you where you want to go at the moment.

Edit after substantial questions and conversation:

You need to supply the additional parameters for the number of textboxes that have not been chosen.

```
int maxPossibleTextBoxCount = 3;
int selectedTextBoxCount = ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Count();
int emptyTextBoxCount = maxPossibleTextBoxCount - selectedTextBoxCount;

using (var command = new SqlCommand("PP_CreateIDNumber", connection)) {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userNum", lblUser.Text);

    int counter = 1;

    // Here we add the parameters for the selected textboxes.
    foreach(TextBox textBox in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@ID{counter++}", textBox.Text);
    }

    // Here we add the parameters for the non-selected textboxes.
    if(emptyTextBoxCount > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < emptyTextBoxCount - 1; i++) {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@ID{counter++}", System.DBNull.Value);
        }
    }

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173125/discussion-on-answer-by-trioj-insert-into-database-using-textbox-control-asp-net).